# Add class on component A with click from child component B | angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

EDIT: I figured out, you need to use event emitters :
http://plnkr.co/edit/FwUYbe5yU0Q58LXqHY7d

What I want to do is when I click on a button in component B, I update class on component A :

Component B

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'panneau-controle',
  template: `

    <div>
      <h1>Mode touch</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" name="mode-touch"  (click)="enableTouch()">
    </div>
  `,

})

export class PanneauComponent {
  enableTouch() {
    return 'touch'
  }
}
```

Component A template : Here I add the class.touch=touch

What I want is when touch is true, it adds the class, and then removes it when you click on the radiobox again

```
<div [class.touch]="touch">
  <panneau-controle></panneau-controle>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <sd-toolbar></sd-toolbar>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <sd-navbar></sd-navbar>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my plunkr :
http://plnkr.co/edit/sxOtRgFFxUZrLb6ELmv0?p=preview

Thank you

Comment: How are component A and B related (parent-child, siblings, other)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I import component B into component A with the selector panneau-controle

Comment: It would be easier to understand if the full metadata and the part of the component A were included in your question.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PZh5CWlYI7kgatgHLPQQ?p=info

Here I made a quick plunker, you can see in hello_world.html I have the [class.touch]="touch", I want that to update with the click in hello_worldB